# Connecting to Bitcoin wallet outside of LAN to 'Solo' Mine

Tags: wallet, miner-configuration, solo-mining, server

For educational purposes only...

Scenario:
My friend and I want to solo mine on 1 wallet. But, his computers are not on\in my LAN network.

The wallet has been set to server mode:
-server

bitcoin.conf
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
server=1

cgminer settings:
-o localhost:port -u user -p name

This works fine for solo mining on just my computer. But how can I change it so that he can connect to my Bitcoin wallet from another state which is obviously outside my LAN?

Comment: You will want to pay attention to this note in the config file: **NOTE: opening up the RPC port to hosts outside your local trusted network is NOT RECOMMENDED, because the rpcpassword is transmitted over the network unencrypted.** An attacker who discovers your rpcpassword can spend your money.

Comment: I think you are confused about the term "solo mining".

Comment: There are possible configurations to do something like what you are looking to do.  But I cant understand why your friend wouldn't want to run his own wallet, on a p2pool configuration, all other users need to specify is the their address. the get block template etc is all done with the local wallet in order to reduce latency and improve performance.

Comment: In terms of unencrypted transmission of the rpcpassword: You may want to setup some kind of P2P VPN first between your friend and yourself to make sure traffic between your nodes cannot be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to throw this into your bitcoin.conf
`rpcallowip=1.1.1.34` where the allowed ip is your friends and also make sure the port isn't going to be blocked by the router.

Is it solo mining? When there is a second party it now becomes pooled mining.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up port forwarding on your router so your bitcoin qt can receive requests. Then add

```
rpcallowip=1.1.1.1.1
```

in your bitcoin.conf where the ip address is your buddy's IP.